# Do Unix systems and other similar systems use the GPU for the startup splash/loading screen (when there is one)?

Tags: ubuntu, macos, gpu, ati, bootsplash

I was wondering if Unix systems use the GPU for the startup splash/loading screen because I've been having some trouble with an overheating Mac with graphics issues. Unix-type systems (such as MacOS 10.6, 10.10 and different versions of Ubuntu) show the splash screen, but never actually boot into the GUI (typically just a plain black/blue/white screen after the startup splash). Windows, however, starts up (I assume this is what's happening as I can hear hard drive activity) and only shows a black screen (no splash or loading screen). This just made me curious as I have a cursed 2008 ATI iMac. I plan later to try reapplying thermal paste to see if that does any good, and then try a reflow (I know this'll only be a very temporary solution but I just want to see if anything will work), but if all else fails, it'll probably go into the bin.

Comment: With Linux, try some of the advanced settings. In Ubuntu, in the initial boot selection, it's F6. Try `nomodeset` `noapic` and `acip=off`. One, or a combination, of them may let you get past the startup screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your literal question is yes: all systems use the GPU to display startup messages and splash screens. That's because going through the GPU is the only way to display something on the monitor.

However, the answer to the question you meant to ask is no: the ways the GPU is used during startup and after the system has fully booted are different. During startup, the operating system uses the GPU in [text mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode) or as a simple [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer). These involve very little work from the GPU, so they are unlikely to trigger GPU bugs or to make it overheat. Text mode is limited in that it can only show text in a single monospace font. Framebuffer mode can show arbitrary images, but it's slow. Both modes may use a resolution that's less than the maximum that the GPU and monitor can do.

Once the system has fully booted, it likely starts using the GPU in a different ways, using its computational capabilities. This involves a complex driver in the operating system, and may involve some nontrivial computation on the GPU. Under Linux, this mode is part of the [X window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (or a replacement for it such as [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland).

You may be able to get a GUI on Linux with the X.org `fbdev` driver (which uses the GPU as a simple framebuffer) or with the X.org [VESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Electronics_Standards_Association) driver (which is a very old standard that does little more than a framebuffer and has limited resolution). It won't be fast, and it might not be pretty, but it's better than nothing.

You may need to work in text mode first to prevent X from starting in a mode that doesn't work. The way to do this depends on the distribution. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console) may be useful even if you don't use Arch. Once you've logged in as root, create or edit [`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Configuration) to choose the video driver. For example, for fbdev, you need something like this (untested):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "fbdev"
    Driver "fbdev"
    Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection
```

You also need to install the appropriate driver (if it isn't already present), which again is distribution-dependent. For example, on Debian/Ubuntu, that's

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
```

Comment: Hi @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil', I tried your solution, however after leaving the mac for a few days, it appears that the graphics glitches have gotten worse :/. After attempting to boot into text mode (on lubuntu), I still had more graphical glitches. I believe the graphics chip on the imac is well and truly gone by now. Otherwise, thanks for your help and answering my question. As this did answer my initial question, I'll leave it as the answer for others who have any similar problems/are just curious. :)